Azure function not able to index functions
Hi I have three azure function written in python, last day I did a minor change in one of them and deployed it. However as we don't have separated deployments for the threee of them the other two got updated as well. After deployi9ng what I thought would be a small change all the functions stopped working. when checking the logs I see this error.
Error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so), Cannot find module. Please check the requirements.txt file for the missing module. For more info, please refer the troubleshooting guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound. Current sys.path: ['/home/site/wwwroot', '/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages', '/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.11/LINUX/X64', '/usr/local/lib/python311.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.11', '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages'] Traceback (most recent call last): File '/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.11/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py', line 44, in call return func(\*args, \*\*kwargs) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File '/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.11/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py', line 244, in index_function_app imported_module = importlib.import_module(module_name) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py', line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>', line 1204, in _gcd_import File '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>', line 1176, in _find_and_load File '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>', line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked File '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>', line 690, in _load_unlocked File '<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>', line 940, in exec_module File '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>', line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed File '/home/site/wwwroot/function_app.py', line 6, in <module> from app.view import view_source_file File '/home/site/wwwroot/app/view.py', line 6, in <module> import storage.blob as blob File '/home/site/wwwroot/storage/blob.py', line 4, in <module> from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobSasPermissions, generate_blob_sas File '/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/__init__.py', line 12, in <module> from ._blob_client import BlobClient File '/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_blob_client.py', line 21, in <module> from ._blob_client_helpers import ( File '/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_blob_client_helpers.py', line 17, in <module> from ._encryption import modify_user_agent_for_encryption, _ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_METHOD_FOR_ENCRYPTION File '/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_encryption.py', line 23, in <module> from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher File '/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/__init__.py', line 11, in <module> from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.base import ( File '/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/base.py', line 10, in <module> from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import openssl as rust_openssl ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so)

I didn´t add any packages just did a small code change, and it was working normal until before the deployment.
I tried to recreate the infrastructure, redeploy code, upgrade Debian version on host. I saw in other post that I maybe should downgrade the python version but this was working before and didn't change anything. Also mention that downgrading will cause other problems with dependencies. I am using python 3.11.
Can somebody help me here_

Please check your Health History in Service Health -> Health History. A global Azure Functions service issue has been occurring for the last 23 hours. Most probably you are affected as well.

Indeed it was a Microsoft problem.
